# How to reference an enum which implements an interface from a generic class

Tags: java, enums

From this context:

```
enum Traits {
   TA,
   TB
}

interface Intrfc {
   Traits getTraits();
}

// How to add some precision about E which implements Traits?
abstract class Base<E extends Enum<E>> {

   void func( E e ) {
      final Traits t = ((Intrfc)e).getTraits(); //<<<<< To avoid this cast?
   }
}

enum X implements Intrfc {
   A( Traits.TA ),
   B( Traits.TA ),
   C( Traits.TB ),
   ;
   private Traits traits;

   X( Traits t ) {
      traits = t;
   }

   @Override
   public Traits getTraits() {
      return traits;
   }
}

class Concrete extends Base<X> {

   void f() {
      func( X.B );
   }
}
```

I wish avoiding the cast by declaring `E` in `Base<E>` with `E implements Traits` but I don't known the syntax to use.

Comment: `E extends Enum<E> & Intrfc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extends` keyword in the generics context can represent both the normal `extends` or the `implements` meanings. So to declare the type parameter as a subtype of the interface you can do the following:

```
abstract class Base<E extends Intrfc> {
```

To have multiple bounds (subtype of both an enum and the interface):

```
abstract class Base<E extends Enum<E> & Intrfc> {
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to force an `enum` too.

Comment: Maybe because it's not frequently encountered in Java code but [here's the reference link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) for it.